# Compiling Qwt for Embedded Debian Linux issues

Tags: qt, qt5, embedded-linux, qwt

I cross compiled Qt5 in my Ubuntu Desktop for an embedded Debian according to http://www.eliasing.com/cubieboard2/qt5-cb2 using gcc-linaro-4.9-2014.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf toolchain.
Then I configured Qt creator and compiled my application on Ubuntu Desktop. I set remote device in Qt creator and it deployed the application on the device. So I could run my application on the device (embedded Debian). Now I want to add Qwt library in my project. According to Qwt's web site I downloaded Qwt source files, cd to sources directory and then run below commands:

```
-qmake qwt.pro

-make -j 4

-sudo make install
```

Running these commands installed Qwt on my Ubuntu desktop. But I have to install it on the device (I have to cross-compile it).  In Qt cross compiling step I set -prefix parameter to /opt/qt/qt5.4-A110. So for first step in Qwt cross compiling I used bellow command:

```
/opt/qt/qt5.4-A110/bin/qmake qwt.pro
```

Then when I run make command I got bellow errors:

> Please submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if
>   appropriate. Please include the complete backtrace with any bug
>   report. See https://bugs.linaro.org for instructions. Makefile:8096:
>   recipe for target 'obj/qwt_plot_curve.o' failed make[1]: ***
>   [obj/qwt_plot_curve.o] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/amvaj/Projects/A110/OS/ClosedHeart/qt/sources/qwt-6.1.3/src'
>   Makefile:45: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first-ordered' failed
>   make: *** [sub-src-make_first-ordered] Error 2

So I thought that I had to set ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE parameters. So I cleaned sources and then used bellow command:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILER=/home/ali/toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

But I got the same errors. What should I do?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!
My toolchain (Linaro 4.9) had internal error and when I was adding QwtPlot, it was crashing!
So solution was very simple. I change my toolchain and downgrade it to Linaro 4.8

for cross compiling we can also use QtCreator. just like any application we have to configure our cross compiler kit and then open qwt.pro and compile the project!